# SQL Queries failing with: The execution of a full-text query failed. "The content index is corrupt."

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Suddenly many queries to my SQL Server 2005 database are failing with this SQL error:

`The execution of a full-text query failed. "The content index is corrupt.`

Anyone know of a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though you may need to rebuild the Full Text Catalog:

[How to: Rebuild a Full-Text Catalog (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326034.aspx)

You may also find the following reference useful.

[Full-Text Catalog and Index How-to Topics (Full-Text Search)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142503.aspx)

Comment: If you happen to be running SQL Management Studio Express (like I am) the full-text stuff doesn't appear in the menus, so you can run this command: `ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG catalog_name REBUILD`